# AngularJS: How to debug the 'App Already Bootstrapped with this Element' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, dry, bootstrapping

In my AngularJS app I'm getting the follwing error when loading my site:

```
Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="ng-scope">'
```

I have `ng-app` only set once (in `html` element in _Layout.cshtml (ASP.NET MVC)) and I don't use `angular.bootstrap` so the issue mentioned [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng%3abtstrpd?p0=%3Chtml%20lang=%22en%22%20ng-app=%22app%22%20class=%22ng-scope%22%3E) should not apply. How can debug the issue (using F12, Firebug, Chrome...)?

Comment: ng-app is applied to _Layout.cshtml. I'd be not surprised that a child page that uses your `_layout` do some init as well. If you remove ng-app from html, what will it be doing?

Comment: Then Angular doesn't work at all...

Comment: Search for ng-app throughout your code

Comment: Search revealed only one place...

Answer (score 2):

Use the following process:

- Download the unminified Angular source
- Switch the script tag to reference the unminified Angular source or setup a sourcemap from the minified code to the unminified
- Set a breakpoint within the `angular.bootstrap` method definition
- Use the call stack to trace the source(s) on the call(s)

**References**

- [Use a source map - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map)
- [F12 devtools guide: Debugger | Source Maps - Microsoft Edge Development](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/debugger/#source-maps)
- [Map Preprocessed Code to Source Code  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/source-maps)
- [Chromium Issue 611328 - Failed to parse SourceMap](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611328)
- [evanw/node-source-map-support: Adds source map support to node.js (for stack traces)](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support)